# Do not save user when validation fails but redirect as if it passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm new to both Ruby and ROR.  I want to present users with validation errors (e.g. password missing, email missing) when they sign up.  If they submit the desired input I create the user and redirect them to the login page  If they provide an email address already in the db and a password that passes validation I don't want to save the user but I do want to redirect them to the login page.  The idea being not to give away who is already a user by presenting them with a duplicate email error.

I've got the signup form working.  I'm just stumped on how to go about also redirecting the user to the login page if they submit a duplicate email and a password that passes validation.  Would I need to setup a custom validation for this?

As an example, assume I have john_doe@yahoo.com in my user table and a user signs up with the following:

```
Case 1:

email = john_doe@yahoo.com
password = null
result = user redirected to sign up page with error about password being blank

Case 2:

email = john_doe@yahoo.com
password = p@55w0rd
result = user redirected to login page with success message

Case 3:

email = sally@yahoo.com
password = p@55w0rd
result = user redirected to login page with success message
```

**UsersController**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user].permit(:email, :password))
    if @user.save
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "signed up!"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

end
```

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end

  def self.authenticate email, password
    user = find_by_email(email)
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      return user
    end

    return nil
  end

  def exists?
    if find_by_email(email)
      return true
    end

    return false
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the else path in your User Controller like this

```
else
      redirect_to login_path
end
```

If you are using devise and simple_form, all those (redirection, displaying error on invalid data) will handled automatically for you.

To add [uniqueness constraint](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) on email, do this in your model:

```
 validates :email, uniqueness: true
```

Comment: Thanks @emaillenin.  I looked at Devise and will likely use that once i"m comfortable with the ins and outs of ROR.  Going back to your suggestion, I wasn't as clear as I could be, so I updated my question to include 3 scenarios.  With your solution I don't believe case 1 would hold true.  Any ideas? Please let me know if I'm mistaken.

Comment: added a validation in my answer

Answer (score 2):

You could specify the redirect in your **UsersController**:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def new
       @user = User.new
    end

    def create
       @user = User.new(params[:user].permit(:email, :password))
       if @user.save
          redirect_to root_url, :notice => "signed up!"
       else
          redirect_to login_url, :notice => "There was something wrong with your e-mail or password"
       end
    end
end
```

I really recommend using Devise - it will take care of these one-off cases for you:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

If you want to be more hands-on with your authentication I would recommend the has_secure_password method:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html
**has_secure_method** takes care of salting your password and does validations as well.

Comment: Definitely will give Devise a shot once I've played around with ROR enough.  Appreciate your help and the link to has_secure_method.